# Wrong available space on usb

Tags: usb, permissions, chromebook

So I'm trying to get my FAT 128gb usb drive to have execute permissions so I can add a steam library in ubuntu 14.04 crouton on my chromebook. I used this:

```
sudo umount /dev/sdb1 
mkdir -p ~/usbdrive 
echo '/dev/sdb1 /home/user/usbdrive vfat rw,exec,uid=1000,gid=1000,umask=022 0 0' | sudo tee -a /etc/fstab
```

I get a usbdrive entry with execute permission but it says it only has 5gb available which is whats left on the internal ssd. How do I fix it so it sees the whole 128gb? Would installing the whole crouton to the usb fix it?

Heres the output you asked for:

```
Model: SanDisk Ultra Fit (scsi)
Disk /dev/sda: 124GB
Sector size (logical/physical): 512B/512B
Partition Table: msdos

Number  Start   End    Size   Type     File system  Flags
 1      16.4kB  124GB  124GB  primary


Model: Linux device-mapper (crypt) (dm)
Disk /dev/mapper/encstateful: 3297MB
Sector size (logical/physical): 512B/512B
Partition Table: loop

Number  Start  End     Size    File system  Flags
 1      0.00B  3297MB  3297MB  ext4


Error: /dev/mmcblk0boot0: unrecognised disk label                         

Error: /dev/mmcblk0boot1: unrecognised disk label                         

Model: MMC SEM16G (sd/mmc)
Disk /dev/mmcblk0: 15.8GB
Sector size (logical/physical): 512B/512B
Partition Table: gpt

Number  Start   End     Size    File system  Name        Flags
11      32.8kB  8421kB  8389kB               RWFW
 6      8421kB  8422kB  512B                 KERN-C
 7      8422kB  8422kB  512B                 ROOT-C
 9      8422kB  8423kB  512B                 reserved
10      8423kB  8423kB  512B                 reserved
 2      10.5MB  27.3MB  16.8MB               KERN-A
 4      27.3MB  44.0MB  16.8MB               KERN-B
 8      44.0MB  60.8MB  16.8MB  ext4         OEM         msftdata
12      128MB   145MB   16.8MB  fat16        EFI-SYSTEM  boot
 5      145MB   2292MB  2147MB  ext2         ROOT-B
 3      2292MB  4440MB  2147MB  ext2         ROOT-A
 1      4440MB  15.7GB  11.3GB  ext4         STATE       msftdata
```

Comment: Are you sure that `/dev/sdb1` is your USB drive? You could add the output of `sudo parted -l /dev/sdb` to your question to give us some more information to work with.

Comment: Looks like `/dev/sda1` is your USB drive...not `/dev/sdb1`. Change your `echo` command to `/dev/sda1` might solve your issue. As well, I think FAT (FAT16) partitions have limited size. Using FAT32 (exFAT) or NTFS would be more beneficial.

Comment: Sorry meant to type sba1 when I put that in, I did that, still no dice.  Reformatted it to ext4, how do I go about giving it execute permissions now?

Answer (score -1):

Just go get format your USB flash with any other file system instead of FAT.

Comment: While this may technically be an answer, it's a very very poor one; there should not be any need to just 'reformat' the filesystem to fix issues.

Comment: If I were to format it to ext4 would it automatically have execute permission?  I'd like to be able to swap it back and forth with my windows machine if thats possible, not exactly sure how it running in a croot affects everything.